# Database schema advice : multiple tables with the shared columns in postgresql

Tags: database-design, postgres

Let's pretend I'm making a basic twitter clone. We could imagine our database is set up as the following:

```
1. Table 1 - contains user info {username, password}
2. Table 2 - contains session info {username, session_id, expire}
3. Table 3 - contains post info {username, post_content, number_of_likes}
```

These tables are basically grouped by function. However `username` is shared between all of them. If a user was to change their username, this would be very hard to maintain since it would have to update across 3 tables. Is there a suggested way to organize user data here? E.g. one giant table? (bleh)  or perhaps a way to centrally reference username so that changing the value once would update all dependent cells? I am using postgresql and am new to the language and databases.

Comment: Read up on "database normalization". That's basically what you're asking about here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical solution would be to introduce a *surrogate key*, i.e. some ID number that's just used within the database. Then we might have a schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  userid bigserial PRIMARY KEY, -- will autoincrement
  username text NOT NULL,
  password blob NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE sessions (
  session_id int NOT NULL,
  userid int REFERENCES users(userid),
  expire timestamp NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE posts (
  postid int PRIMARY KEY,
  userid int REFERENCES users(userid),
  content text NOT NULL,
  likes int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

But you don't need it. You can still use the username as a natural key. You are concerned that

> If a user was to change their username, this would be very hard to maintain since it would have to update across 3 tables.

But such an update would be fairly easy. You could explicitly create a `TRANSACTION` consisting of multiple queries, one updating each table.

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  UPDATE users ...;
  UPDATE sessions ...;
  UPDATE posts ...;

COMMIT;
```

Or, more realistically, we could use a `REFERENCES` clause in the table definition to track updates. You already came up with this solution yourself:

> or perhaps a way to centrally reference username so that changing the value once would update all dependent cells?

In our table definition, we'd can `CASCADE` such changes with a column definition like

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  username text REFERENCES users(username) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ...
);
```

Then, you can `DELETE` all of one user's data just by deleting their entry in the `users` table, or update their username in all tables just by updating it in the `users` table.

The point here is that RDBMS like Postgres are really mature systems with lots of features. These features generally help with keeping the data consistent – you can add constraints like the `REFERENCES` clause to ensure that no entries in the other tables can exist without a matching row in the `users` table, but you can also use such features to automatically update all of the dependent data.